# Generate an id starting from one on every new date in C# using SQL server database

Tags: c#, database, auto-generate

Please help me to do this.
Generate an id from database but id should start from one on each new date.
Using c# and SQL server.

Comment: [This link](https://www.google.com) will get you started.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question will probably be closed soon because it is overly broad and non-specific, but don't let that deter you from seeking help. Please see how to ask a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and improve your question.

Comment: See my answer hopefully that will work

Answer (score 0):

Please modify below SQL procedure based on your requirement

```
create proc [dbo].[InsertRecord]
    as
    begin
        declare @ID int=0;
        if (select count(1) from table_1 where CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CurrentDate,10)=CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),10))=0
            begin
                set @ID=1;
            end
        else 
            begin
                set @ID=(select top 1 ID from table_1 order by CurrentDate desc);
                set @ID=isnull(@ID,0)+1;
            end

        insert into table_1(ID,CurrentDate)values(@ID,GETDATE());
        select * from table_1;
    end
```